# Command "git push origin main" paralysed my terminal

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am a programming beginner trying to use git and GitHub trying to keep track of a small project. I have done this a few times, but today I faced a strange issue.

After untracking some files with `git rm --cached <filename>` , I added and commited. Then I pulled (as I think is good practice before pushing) and tried to push. But when I entered `git push origin main`, there was no result. No fatal, nor output at all. Blank terminal. Would be at least fine if it was not for the fact that my username and folder did not appear in the next line, so commands couldn't be prompted. Only way out was `^C`. I will add the commands I have used while working on this repository:

```
git init

git add . && git commit -m "Starting project"

git log

git status

git branch

git branch -m master main

git status

git remote add origin (URL)

git remote

git pull origin main --allow-unrelated-histories

git push origin HEAD:main

git pull origin main

git loggit diff (id1) (id2)

git rm --cached (files)

git status

git rm --cached (file I forgot to include)

git commit -am "removed files"

git pull origin main

git push origin main

git push origin HEAD:main
```

It is this last push which is not working. There are two pushes because the first one did not work, and the second one did not as well.

System: Ubuntu 20.04 under WSL2 in Windows 10. Using both Windows Terminal and VSC terminal, none worked.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try running your push with `GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` and including the output here, redacting any Authorization headers.

Comment: Somehow it asked me for my username and PAT again. Thanks, but could you please explain me how or why your solution worked?

Comment: What I asked is just for debugging; it shouldn't change anything.  If things work now, then it's probably that you had some sort of network problem or other transitory issue that made things not work.